# Angular 5. Build AOT

Tags: angular, jit, angular5, angular-aot

In Angular 5 I'm having an error using: `ng serve --aot`

if I build with JIT (at-loader) then everything is working, but I need AOT.

Here you can see the discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20639

Help me, please.

[image]

Comment: In `angular 5` by default its `aot`

Comment: @Aravind yes, by default. But, I have errors if use key `--aot`. If I use JIT(`ng serve`) then everything is working.

Comment: Can you provide reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

For compiling / Livesync, you no need to use `--aot` flag.

To Build your project, use

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

if you use `--aot` while serving, it will build your whole project with ContantInvalidating. By doing only `ng serve` it will run with `AOT` functionality

Comment: @ Deepak swain - in the latest angularCLI versions, you just need the command: "ng build --prod", without "--aot", as this is run by default when building for production.

Answer (score 0):

angular v5+ have default **aot** so you can easily build your app with using for production **ng build --prod**